# How should I use the Spring WebClient to non-interactively access an OAuth protected resource on behalf of another user?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring (not Boot) application which has to access non-interactively (in a scheduled task) some 3rd-party resources on behalf of our users. These resources use OAuth 2.0 for authorization. We already have a workflow that gets us the required tokens and are accessing the resources using either Spring Social or our own implementation neither of which is optimal (Spring Social seems to be not maintained, we'd rather use a library than maintain our OAuth "framework").

I'm trying to use the `WebClient` from Spring Security 5.1, but I'm not sure I'm using it correctly.

The `WebClient` is created this way:

```
final ClientRegistration 3rdParty = 3rdParty();

final ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository =
    new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(3rdParty);

final ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService =
    new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository);

final ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository =
    new AuthenticatedPrincipalServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository(authorizedClientService);

final ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction autorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction =
    new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);

return WebClient.builder()
    .filter(autorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction)
    .build();
```

and accessing the resource this way works:

```
final OAuth2AuthorizedClient oAuth2AuthorizedClient = ... // (OAuth2AuthorizedClient with OAuth2AccessToken)

final Mono<SomeResource> someResourceMono = webClient().get()
    .uri(3rdpartyUrl)
    .attributes(ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.oauth2AuthorizedClient(oAuth2AuthorizedClient))
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(SomeResource.class);
```

The problem is I don't see how the `ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository` and `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` are used in this approach. If I have to create a fully populated `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` to access the resource, why are these repositories needed?

I expected, that I have to pass the clientRegistrationId, some "principalName", implement our `ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService` loading `OAuth2AuthorizedClient`'s by "principalName" and let the `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` do its work, but the only way I see to pass a principal to the WebClient is by using `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction#oauth2AuthorizedClient` which requires a complete `OAuth2AuthorizedClient`. Which is the part I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of supplying the `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` via `oauth2AuthorizedClient()`, you can also provide the `clientRegistrationId` via `clientRegistrationId()` and `ServerWebExchange` via `serverWebExchange()`. The combination of the latter 2 options will resolve the `Principal` from the `ServerWebExchange` and use both `ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository` and `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` to resolve the `OAuth2AuthorizedClient`. I understand your use-case is a bit different given you are running outside of a request context - this is just a FYI.

> ...The problem is I don't see how the
>   ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository and
>   ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository are used in this approach

You still need to provide `ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository` and `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` as the `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction` supports the refreshing (`authorization_code` client) and renewing (`client_credentials` client) of an expired access token.

For your specific use case, take a look at `UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` as this implementation supports `WebClient` running outside of a request context, e.g. background thread. Here is a [sample](https://github.com/rwinch/webclientoauth2-cli) for your reference.